# Searching for item in JSON with node js

Tags: node.js, json, discord

I'm trying to make a command that when a user types !info his category is filtered on the JSON file

JSON file:

```
[
    {
      "discordidexample": {
        "Name": "User1"
        "Tag": "#5432"
        "Account-Created": "11-04-2017"
      }
    }
  },
  {
      "discordidexample": {
        "Name": "User2"
        "Tag": "#9742"
        "Account-Created": "19-01-2019"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: JOSN look like this {key:value, key2:value2}, you have a array in the example

Answer (score 0):

```
function main() { 

    let data = [
        {
            "discordidexample": {
                "Name": "User1"
        "Tag": "#5432"
        "Account-Created": "11-04-2017"
            }
        }
        ,
        {
            "discordidexample": {
                "Name": "User2"
        "Tag": "#9742"
        "Account-Created": "19-01-2019"
            }
        }
    ];

    // this is a array if json not a json

    // to find elements you can do a map, foreach 

    data.forEach(elemnt => {
        console.log(elemnt.discordidexample.Name);
        console.log(elemnt.discordidexample.Tag);
        console.log(elemnt.discordidexample.Account-Created);

        //make your validation here

    })


    //

    data = data.filter(elemnt => { 
        //make your validation here
        //example 
        if (elemnt.discordidexample.Name == "User1") {
            return elemnt
        } 
    })

    //name has to be unique
    if (data.length > 0) {
        console.log("I have this name here:", data[0].discordidexample.Name); // User1
    }  

}

main();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Hello Daniel thanks for the solution, this seems to work.
I have two questions: 

1: The "discordidexample" is replaced with the Discord ID of the user who is doing the command, so my idea was to do: 
elemnt.member.Tag because my "member" is the Discord ID of the user who execute the cmd --> this is not working i got a error: Name is not definied.

2: How do I use a .json instead of an array in this data case?